# phpMyAdmin: How to insert rows with restricted columns?

Tags: mysql, permissions, phpmyadmin, mariadb, privileges

I have a table with auto-incremented ID, colA and colB (with set default value), e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_db`.`test` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `colA` INT NOT NULL , `colB` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now, I want user to be able to insert the new row, but at the same time DO NOT allow to modify `id` (auto-incremented) or `colB` (just use default value).

Is that possible?

I tried to give INSERT and UPDATE only for colA, but that still gives me `INSERT command denied` error:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT (`colA`), UPDATE (`colA`) ON `some_db`.`test` TO 'test_user'@'%';
```

I don't know if that matters, I'm using MariaDB.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
OK, I need to re-state my question now.

After executing e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`colA`) VALUES (10)
```

**Everything is working fine.**
But phpmyadmin GUI (that I use as a front-end here) is translating to:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `colA`, `colB`) VALUES (NULL, 10, ``)
```

...when no values are given, and it can't be executed (#1143 - INSERT command denied to user `test_user@...`

So, **is there any way that rows can be inserted through phpmyadmin GUI (not SQL command) with such restrictions?** (I edited the question title).

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: *But phpmyadmin GUI (that I use as a front-end here) is translating to* Do not use it, what a problem? use any other client. PS. If the program does not do what you said, but what it came up with - do not use such a program.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `test` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
>                       `colA` INT NOT NULL , 
>                       `colB` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , 
>                       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_test
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON test
> FOR EACH ROW
> SET NEW.id = NULL, NEW.colB = 0;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test (colA) VALUES (11);
> INSERT INTO test (colA, colB) VALUES (22, 222);
> INSERT INTO test (id, colA) VALUES (3333, 33);
> INSERT INTO test (id, colA, colB) VALUES (4444,44,444);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> | id | colA | colB |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 11 | 0 |
> | 2 | 22 | 0 |
> | 3 | 33 | 0 |
> | 4 | 44 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=001dc6af158905a8a9afcb119a72fe99)*

---

You cannot use `DEFAULT` keyword for assigning the value to `NEW.colB` - in MariaDB it is treated as NULL while using in a trigger. So you need to hardcode this default value, or you may query it from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the effort and having a look! Please have a look at edit above: actually it IS working, the problem lies in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Art I don't use phpmyadmin. I don't advise you either.

Comment: Yeah I know, problem is that so far I haven't found any simple, free, easy to use and setup, GUI client that will allow drop-down choice for reference key (rather than providing numeric IDs) and phpMyAdmin was doing it nicely. I know its a stupid thing but thats what I need now.